# Does Apache Ignite support WAN replication?

Tags: replication, ignite, wan

I've been doing some experiments with Apache Ignite and I've started to look into WAN replication. By this I mean there would be 2 (or more) data centres each running an Ignite cluster. There would be some caches that I would like kept in sync between the two data centres.

Does Apache Ignite support this? If so how is this configured as I can't find any mention of this in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment Ignite does not support caches spanning multiple clusters(nor cache mirroring). If however you mean there is only one Ignite cluster consisting of nodes located in different data centers(WAN),that would be possible though would most likely be inefficient! since you will have to use the [Replicated Mode](http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/v1.1/docs/cache-modes#replicated-mode).

Comment: Thanks, explains why I find no mention in the documentation. I look forward to the day when this is no longer the correct answer on SO.

Answer (score 2):

GridGain provides asynchronous WAN replication on top of Ignite as part of their payed solution: https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/data-center-replication/configuring-replication